# Yii2 model get method for field containing underscore

Tags: php, model, yii2, getter-setter

Model name: `listing`;
Field name: `contact_name`.

User input involved, so I want to format the output, consistently, with some variant of `getContactName`, i.e. any call to `$model->contact_name` returns the formatted output.  Yes, I can use, for example, `getContactName` and `$model->contactName`, but I have not found any variant of `getcontact_name` that will work with the default `$model->contact_name`.

I'm aware that I could configure Gii to create some additional functions, and various other workarounds, but I'm interested, after a decent Google, in whether there is a straightforward solution.

Comment: so what you want is that whenever you have a model loaded with values from database or you call `Model::find()->all()` and you try to access the `$model->contact_name` you need the default value say `rich-harding` formatted as `Rich Harding` ?

Comment: Yes, and I realise that, before asking the question, I'd just got a little bit too deep into the trees to see the wood. @rob006 has put me back on the path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getContact_name()` will not work if you already have attribute (or regular object property) with `contact_name` as a name. Attributes from database have precedence over getters/setters - you can see this in [`__get()` source code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/e53fc0ded1d7299351a65cc451632cd22bff6684/framework/db/BaseActiveRecord.php#L287-L289). And obviously `__get()` will never be called if you have real property with this name. So value will be searched in this order:

1. [Object properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).
2. Attributes from database.
3. Getters/setters (including relations).

You should either use different name (`contactName`), or do formatting using `afterFind` event or override `__get()` to change order of data sources (this could be tricky). You may be also interested in [this PR](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/16496).

Comment: I think you've hit upon the answer here and that I was believing, in error, that the reason that I couldn't make it work was the underscore. I will do some more testing, but I'll mark as Accepted, for now at least.

Answer (score 3):

You can override the `afterFind()` method for your desired model and override the default value , or format the default value to your desired format.
You can override the method by adding the below into your model `Listing`.

Lets say we need to format the default contact name which is saved like `rich-harding` in the table and we will format it as `Rich Harding`

```
public function afterFind() {
    parent::afterFind();
    $names=explode("-",$this->contact_name);
    $this->contact_name=implode(" ", array_map('ucfirst',$names));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I like this answer, because I already have an afterFind for this model. However I'll not, if you don't mind, mark it as accepted - yet - because I'd really like to know if it can be accomplished with a simple get.

Comment: @RichHarding i could not understand the last part, what do you mean by **"Really like to know if it can be accomplished with a simple get"**

Comment: see the answer from rob006 and my response to it.