# Yii2 property of object

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

In my database I have:
region table with fileds

```
 -id
 -name
```

and flower table

```
 -id
 -name
 -region - this is ID from ragion table
```

in my Flower model I have method

```
public function getRegion()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Region::className(), ['id' => 'region']);
    }
```

and now when I try to use it like this

```
$flower->region->name
```

I got error `Trying to get property of non-object`

```
$flower->region
```

return ID of region. How can I get name of region by use

```
$flower->region->name
```

?

update:
when I use gii to generate Flower model I got this method:

```
public function getRegion0()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Region::className(), ['id' => 'region']);
    }
```

I dont get it. Why I cant use simple getRegion()

Comment: Theoretically, it should work... I would assume you missed something during the configuration... check: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record

Comment: it can't be the same name, should be something like region_id in flower table. I dont know how to overwrite getter region in Flower model

Comment: I used gii to generate Flower model and I got method  getRegion*0*(), I don't get it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use the same name for relation as for DB attribute. Attributes from database have precedence over methods ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51754047/5812455) explains how value for property will be searched). If you have attribute with `region` as name, it will be used instead of attribute/relation provided by method `getRegion()`. Gii is smart enough to generate relation wit different name - although `region0` is not really good name, it works.

In your case the best way would be to rename `region` column to `region_id` - column name becomes more clear and you get rid of names conflicts between relation and attribute names.